# Click event is not firing in PowerBuilder on single line edit control

Tags: events, powerbuilder, click

In child window of my application, I have placed one single line edit control named as sle_name. Its tab order is 1.

Below that control I have placed DataWindow having formatted as free form style.

When I run the app, if my focus is in sle_name, and I click on sle_name then rbuttondown event is triggered. Then I move my focus to DataWindow(dw_account). Once I got focus on dw_account and then if I try to click on sle_name, my focus is not moving on sle_name and neither I can run rbuttondown event on sle_name.

What is the reason for this problem?

One more thing: when I start this window my focus in set in sle_name, from that control if I press tab key then my focuse moves to dw_account and if I press again shift+tab then my focus is moved back to sle_account.

But if I try to set focus from dw_account to sle_account using mouse pointer it is not moving focus.

What is the reason behind this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have some data edition pending in the DW when it got focus? (do you insert some new line?) Maybe that you can't leave the focused DW because of a validation error.

Comment: What version of PowerBuilder are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior in a child window.
It was fixed when disabled the 'ControlMenu' and 'TitleBar' properties in the window. (It's so strange).

Hope it helps

Juanma

Answer (score 0):

This isn't natural behaviour, so the cause is likely something you've scripted. Depending on your architecture, the culprit code could be a number of places (e.g. framework objects). If this were my problem, I'd run with the PBDEBUG trace turned on (a System Option in the IDE, or /PBDEBUG on the command line after the deployed EXE name), and see what is firing when you try to move back to the SLE.

I'd also be using [PBL Peeper](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PBL_Peeper/Download/download.html) to see the trace and the code side-by-side, so it's easier to see what code is being executed (the trace only shows you script name and line number).

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to create the event ID **pbm_lbuttonup**, with the same parameter as **rbuttondown** event. Then in the code you write this.setfocus()